# How to create similar colour in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uicolor

I have this generated colour and want to get three similar colours of mainViewColor

```
float red = arc4random() % 256 / 255.0;
float green = arc4random() % 256 / 255.0;
float blue = arc4random() % 256 / 255.0;

UIColor *mainViewColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
self.mainView.backgroundColor = mainViewColor;
```

Comment: and you are asking about what?

Comment: Similar, how?  Different shades, or same shade but different hues?

Comment: if mainViewColor is red, i want to get 3 nearest colors to red

Answer (score 1):

To get different shades, use [UIColor's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:) `-getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` to work with [HSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and then create new colors using 
`+colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:`

```
CGFloat hue, saturation, brightness;
[mainViewColor getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness];

// Helper to keep c in "good" range of (0, 1)
CGFloat wrap(CGFloat c) {
  if(c > 1.0f) {
    return c - 1.0f;
  }else if(c < 0.0f) {
    return c + 1.0;
  }
  return c;
}

// Creates 3 "similar" colors with different brightness.
NSMutableArray* similarColors = [NSMutableArray new];
[similarColors addObject:[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:wrap(brightness + 0.2)]];
[similarColors addObject:[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:wrap(brightness + 0.4)]];
[similarColors addObject:[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:wrap(brightness - 0.2)]];
```